# Solve the inequality $\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x}) \leq e^{cx^2}$ with series

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, power-series, taylor-expansion

The inequality I have to solve is: find $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the inequality $\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x}) \leq e^{cx^2}$ is verified for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

My exercises book suggests to use the series expansion, this is my attempt: I've written $\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})=\cosh x$ and I've expanded both sides:
$$\cosh x \leq e^{cx^2} \iff \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(cx^2)^k}{k!} \iff \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c^k x^{2k}}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{2^k k!} \geq 0$$
$$\iff \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(c^k-\frac{1}{2^k}\right) \frac{x^{2k}}{k!}\geq0$$
Since $\frac{x^{2k}}{k!} \geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the only possibility for the series to be positive is if it is
$$c^k-\frac{1}{2^k} \geq 0 \iff c^k \geq \frac{1}{2^k} \iff |c| \geq \frac{1}{2} \iff c \geq \frac{1}{2} \lor c \leq -\frac{1}{2}$$
However the answer in the book considers only $c \geq \frac{1}{2}$; I've considered $|c|$ for even $k$, where am I wrong? Is it somehow related to the fact that for $c \leq -\frac{1}{2}$ I am summing negative numbers and so there is some problems in the inequality resolution and so I must impose $c \geq 0$ as well? Thanks to anyone who will answer.

Comment: My first obsrvation is that $(2k)! \neq 2^k k!$. You may confuse it with the equality $2^k k! = (2k)!!$. First show that $c \geq \frac{1}{2}$ is enough and then that it is necessary.

Comment: Also note that $c^k \geq \frac{1}{2^k} \iff |c| \geq \frac{1}{2}$ holds for even $k$ but not for odd $k.$

Answer (score 1):

your problem arises from the conclusion that $c^k\geq\frac{1}{2^k}$ imples that $|c|\geq\frac{1}{2}$ for take $c=2$ then using your conclusion we get $2\leq-\frac{1}{2}$ which is wrong.
on the other hand, notice that the right hand side of the inequality is positive, hence the left hand side being greater than the right, it is always positive and therefore $c$ cannot be negative, so that $c\geq\frac{1}{2}$ $$.
$$
in general $c^k\leq\frac{1}{2^k}$ imples that $|c|\leq\frac{1}{2}$, not the other way around.